# Openshift post deploy script with nohup

Tags: python, scripting, openshift, nohup

I am writing python Flask web application which I am deploying on Openshift in container (Python S2I image). Then, after deployment, I want to run 1 python process and 1 celery worker. I am using for that post lifecycle hook in deployment pod [image: settings in openshift]

My script runFirst.py is presented beloew - I am using nohup & to put this processes in the bacground:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import subprocess
import os

print("start")
subprocess.run(['nohup', 'python', 'app/services/consumer.py', '</dev/null', 
'> nohup1.out', '2>nohup1.out', '&'])
subprocess.run(['nohup', 'celery', '-A', 'app.celery', 'worker', '-- 
pool=eventlet', '</dev/null', '> nohup2.out', '2>nohup2.out', '&'])
print("end")
```

However, after I deploy pod, I get following logs, which prove that scripts does not run to the end and it is not putting processes in the background:

```
--> post: Running hook pod ...
start
Consumer is working...
```

Moreover, when I enter the pod and check processes with "top" command, I cannot see that process.

Comment: The 'post' life cycle hook runs in a container of its own, which will then be stopped. You want to use a 'postStart' action run in the pod of the deployment instead. It isn't necessarily a great way to start secondary processes though.

Comment: So which method would you recommend to start processes?

Comment: Depends on whether is non scalable application and it needs to run in the same container due to access to a local file system database such as SQLite. If is only one replica ever and needs file system access, you could introduce supervisord into the container. If using database like PostgreSQL/MySQL, the celery worker instance could be run in separate container of same pod, if only ever one replica. Alternatively deploy celery worker in totally separate deployment.

Comment: Thank you for your answers! However, I am trying with postStart lifecycle and I still cannot make it work.. I see only logs from flask app and I cannot see even "echo TEST" command

Comment: Don't think ``stdout`` of ``postStart`` will go to container log. Try ``echo TEST > /proc/1/fd/1``. This will explicitly send it to stdout of the container it is run in.